# Show $w,L(w),L^2(w),\dots,L^{n-1}$ are linearly independent

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $W$ be an finite dimensional vector space.

The dimension of $W$ is $n$. Let $L:W\rightarrow W$ be linear.

Define $L^0=I_W$ and $L^k=L\circ L\circ \cdots \circ L$ for $k$ times.

If there exists $w\in W$ such that $L^{n-1}(w)\ne 0$ and $L^n(w)=0$.

Show $w,L(w),L^2(w),\dots,L^{n-1}$ are linearly independent.

It is easy to show that a few vectors are linearly independent, but how can I show that $n$ vectors are?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose

$$\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}a_kL^kw=0$$

Apply now $\;L^{n-1}\;$ to both sides of the last equality:

$$a_0L^{n-1}w+a_1\overbrace{L^nw}^{=0}+\ldots+a_{n-1}\overbrace{L^{2(n-1)}w}^{=0}=0\implies a_0L^{n-1}w=0\implies a_0=0$$

Now take off $\;a_0\;$ from the first equality and repeat the above with applying $\;L^{n-2}\;$ in both sides, and then induction...